# Python Unicode Encode Decode Issue

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8

Lets take a simple variable -

```
var =  u' \u2013 2'
```

Lets try decoding it -

```
var.decode('utf-8')
```

I get the following error -

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Lets try encoding it -

```
var.encode('utf-8')
```

I get the following error -

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

One solution is to do -

```
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Let me know, what others are doing?

Comment: where are you running this?

Comment: You just don't understand the difference between `unicode` and `bytes`. Python 27 did not manage to get it right however: unicode objects have a `.decode` method, and bytestrings have a `.encode` which is a non sense.

Answer (score 2):

> Lets try decoding [a Unicode string]

You *decode* bytes to Unicode. You *encode* Unicode to bytes.

You cannot decode a `unicode` string.

If you try, Python tries to help you out by automatically converting the Unicode string to something it can decode: a byte string. As this is implicit, it uses the default encoding for your platform, which is ASCII. ASCII can't encode U+2013 so you have an error.

(With hindsight, this attempt at “do what I mean” behaviour was a mistake. Python 3 no longer allows it.)

> I get 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

You're doing something else there you haven't shown us, then, because encoding works fine:

```
>>> u' \u2013 2'.encode('utf-8')
' \xe2\x80\x93 2'
```

> One solution is to do sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

This was never a proper solution to anything, which is why Python takes some steps to prevent you doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
>>> var =  u' \u2013 2'
```

creates a Unicode string object inside your program. The mistake you appear to be making is assuming that Unicode objects are encoded: they aren't, they are in a form suitable for direct use by Python code.

When you want to transmit the Unicode string, you have to do so as a sequence of bytes, which means your string must be *encoded*.

```
>>> var.encode("utf-8")
```

gives the result

```
' \xe2\x80\x93 2'
```

which is indeed your original string encoded in UTF-8. You can verify this with

```
>>> var.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

which gives you back the original Unicode string:

```
u' \u2013 2'
```

Remember - decode on the way in (to convert an external representation into a Unicode object), encode on the way out (so your Unicode objects can be represented as byte strings).